# Unresolved import error in VSCode with PyDev?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, redis, pydev

I deleted an old Python version (3.6) from my PC, but after that the VSCode underlining my imports (redis, pandas etc). The codes are perfectly running, but the red underline is kinda annoying. Any idea how could I solve this problem? I'm using Python 3.8.5 64-bit ('base':conda) as a default interpreter. The error message: Unresolved import: redisPyDev(6).

This is the test code:

```
import redis 

redis_host = ""
redis_port = 

r = redis.Redis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port, db=0, decode_responses=True)

print(r.get('str_id'))
```

Comment: What is the code you used for testing? Which one provided this "Unresolved import: redisPyDev" information? (Python extension or Pylint?)

Comment: I updated the description. The code works just fine, but when i'm hovering to the underlined redis keyword, this error shows up. Probably Pylint problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the information you provided, "`Unresolved import: redisPyDev`" is provided by the VS Code extension "`PyDev`". If you do not use this extension, please try to "disable" it.

Usually, when we use python in VS Code, many of its functions are provided by [the Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python). When I did not install the module "redis", here is the "unresolved import'redis'" information provided by the python extension:

[image]

After we installed the module "redis", then reload VS Code, no errors or warnings are displayed here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I disabled the PyDev extension, and the red underline is gone! It's kinda weird bug, because the extension worked just fine with older Python version. I don't really know what happened. Redis was already installed by the way. Thanks again for the help!